# Is it possible to modify free-functions's implementation, in graal-js?

Tags: javascript, java, interop, graalvm

Recently i have been using GraalVm to execute javascript files from java.
I have the need to reimplement the print() function but i didn't figure out how.
I tried messing with some Bindings's methods and GraalJSScriptEngine's methods, but i didn't get what i was looking for.
Then how can i achieve this?
Note: the implementation of the new print() has to be done in java

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found out how to do that.
It was enough to do this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = ...
engine.put("print", new Function<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(String msg) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            return null;
        }
    });
```